# defining variables in excel formulas?

Tags: excel, variables, formula

i have a simple table data like:

```
date     | Jenna | Tom | Robin
01/01/12    2       5       8
02/01/12    3       4       7
```

(date columns starts from the first day of the year and goes all the way down to he next year.)

I have a formula getting the min. and max. values (for example for Jenna) for the month January.

I have to change the row numbers every month to get the right result.

Is it possible for me to define variables in two cells and use them in that formula without using VBA.
For example;

I will put two values in **H1 and H2** cells, which are **28 and 58** respectively. And i will define E1 as start and E2 as end. And write down this formula:

```
=min(Cstart:Cend)
=max(Cstart:Cend)
=average(Cstart:Cend)
```

The first formula means to get the min value between the **C28 and C58**.

That way i will not have to change every formula manually on the page. I will just change the values of 2 cells and that will be enough.

I hope, I have explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You have to use the `INDIRECT()` function.  `INDIRECT` transforms a string to a range reference.

```
=MIN(INDIRECT("C" & $H$1 &":C" & $H$2))
```

Comment: I will try it to see if i get it right. I guess, this is the thing i've been looking for. Thank you.